# Call specific REST API method based on role

Tags: rest, amazon-iam

I have two roles role_1 and role_2. When an REST API end point

```
@Path("delete-key")
```

is called by users with role_1 I would like to call delete_method_1 and if its called by users with role_2 I would like to call delete_method_2. Something like this

```
@DELETE
@Path("delete-ukey")
public Response delete_method_1() {
}
```

And

```
@DELETE
@Path("delete-ukey")
public Response delete_method_2() {
}
```

In above code, end point is same, However I am not sure how I can add role to call delete_method_1 and delete_method_2

Not sure if I can use

```
@scope
```